# Facebook Graph API: Parser error: unexpected end of query

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, fql.multiquery

I'm trying to retrieve facebook insights data using the multiquery FQL method but to no avail. I've followed the instructions available on facebook's [site](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/fql/).

Does anybody have any idea as to what might be missing or done wrong?

**Queries (works using the Graph API Explorer)**

```
SELECT metric, value FROM insights WHERE object_id=310852659027337 AND metric='page_views' AND period=86400 AND end_time=end_time_date('2014-01-16')

SELECT metric, value FROM insights WHERE object_id=310852659027337 AND metric='page_views_unique' AND period=86400 AND end_time=end_time_date('2014-01-16')
```

**Request URL**

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?access_token=access_token&format=json&queries=%7B%22page_views%22%3A+%22SELECT+metric%2C+value+FROM+insights+WHERE+object_id%3D310852659027347+AND+metric%3D%27page_views%27+AND+period%3D86400+AND+end_time%3Dend_time_date%28%272014-01-16%27%29%22%2C+%22page_views_unique%22%3A+%22SELECT+metric%2C+value+FROM+insights+WHERE+object_id%3D310852659027347+AND+metric%3D%27page_views_unique%27+AND+period%3D86400+AND+end_time%3Dend_time_date%28%272014-01-16%27%29%22%7D
```

**Request URL (Decoded)**

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?access_token=access_token&format=json&queries={"page_views": "SELECT metric, value FROM insights WHERE object_id=310852659027347 AND metric='page_views' AND period=86400 AND end_time=end_time_date('2014-01-16')", "page_views_unique": "SELECT metric, value FROM insights WHERE object_id=310852659027347 AND metric='page_views_unique' AND period=86400 AND end_time=end_time_date('2014-01-16')"}
```

**Response**

```
{"error":{"message":"(#601) Parser error: unexpected end of query.","type":"OAuthException","code":601}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> https://graph.facebook.com/fql?access_token=access_token&format=json&queries={"page_views":
>   "SELECT metric, value FROM insights WHERE object_id=310852659027347
>   AND metric='page_views' AND period=86400 AND
>   end_time=end_time_date('2014-01-16')", "page_views_unique": "SELECT
>   metric, value FROM insights WHERE object_id=310852659027347 AND
>   metric='page_views_unique' AND period=86400 AND
>   end_time=end_time_date('2014-01-16')"}

No such parameter name named **queries**, the correct parameter name is **q**, i.e.

https://graph.facebook.com/fql?access_token=access_token&format=json&q={"page_views": "SELECT metric, value FROM insights WHERE object_id=310852659027347 AND metric='page_views' AND period=86400 AND end_time=end_time_date('2014-01-16')", "page_views_unique": "SELECT metric, value FROM insights WHERE object_id=310852659027347 AND metric='page_views_unique' AND period=86400 AND end_time=end_time_date('2014-01-16')"}

Documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/fql/

Comment: That works. Thanks.
The facebook api documentation has incorrect information. It mentions passing a query param called "queries" (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/fql/).

Facebook's API doc says "
Evaluates a series of FQL (Facebook Query Language) queries in one call and returns the data at one time.

This method takes a JSON-encoded dictionary called ''queries'' where the individual queries use the exact same syntax as a simple query."